# .NET - How share data between service and azure function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have a problem regarding data sharing between services. I have Service1, where I have a configuration stored, which is set on the frontend in the database - archiving time, etc. Next to that I have Service2 (which is a couple of azure functions) which has its own database. Once a day I would need to delete old data in Service2 using the time function. However, in this time function I need the configuration from service1. To be honest I don't know exactly how to approach this. Service1 holds this configuration because it is a miscellaneous configuration and not just a configuration to delete archive data.

- I was thinking of keeping the configuration in Service1 and in case of modification via Service bus, notifying Service2 who will save it. However, this is where the common problem of data being stored in both places arises.
- Keeping this only in Service2, where I now override it via Service1 (service bus), but in the future it could for example be called via the api gateway? However, here's the problem again, if I need to display this data on a frontend that looks into service1, I don't know exactly how to do that.
- In service1 store the data in a table and for example table storage and then take it from service2. But again, there is duplication of data.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the scenario is but sounds like you have a web app that's configuring several settings, and among those setting some are for the backend service (Functions). If that's the case, I see no problem dispatching a copy to the backend service when a change occurs. Alternatively, provide a configuration ID when a change occurs and backend query by ID to get the settings if it's not needed frequently. But from what I read, it would be required for the execution. Alternatively, storing the data not in the DB associated with the webappp but rather something like Storage table.

Comment: @SeanFeldman Maybe I misspoke. I'm sorry. Both Service1 and Service2 are backends. In service1 I have tables for settings in which I store configurations, after what time to delete data, how often etc. I can change these settings using the frontend. In service2 I have a timer function that deletes old records, but it needs to get the settings from service1 and this is the problem and I don't know how exactly to approach this.

Comment: I'd try the route of publishing that information or having the two services access it. Service 1 would be writing/reading and Service 2 reading only.

Comment: @SeanFeldman Thank you very much. So you mean something like store data in service1 in blob storage and then take it? Or do you mean for service1 to send all changes to service2 and it keeps its copy? I suppose it's probably more like the first option right? Or can you explain this more please? Thanks a lot

Comment: Both options are possible. Depending on the scenario, I'd start with the first one initially.

Comment: @SeanFeldman ok thank you. Can you please write you comment as answer? I would like mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two services need to share configuration, it could be accomplished in several ways. The two scenarios you could try would be:

1. One service can read and modify the settings. When settings are modified, it announces (publishes an event) to communicate the change. That's assuming the second service doesn't have direct access to the persistence.
2. Allow both services to read the settings, but only one of the services can write.

I'd try to pursue the first path because it's more scalable and less prone to issues of who's in charge of the data. It also removes the need to keep all services aware of the credentials. And, services can scale out, be added, and still get notified about the settings change.